# Orthogonal polynomial and Taylor series approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

For an analytic nonlinear function, does the statement always hold ``Orthogonal polynomial based linearization (first-order approximation) will be expected to be more accurate than first-order Taylor series approximation"?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "more accurate". In general, a Taylor polynomial is useless for approximating points of a function unless they're close to the point at which you're approximating. Approximation techniques with orthogonal polynomials tend to at least try to be a decent approximation on an interval.

Comment: Thanks @TheoBendit Can you suggest some reference where I can find the superiority of orthogonal approximation over Taylor expansion.

Comment: I don't have anything specific in mind, I'm sorry. Much of my own understanding of the topic comes from learning some theory behind generalised Fourier series at uni, as well as some general functional analysis.